# Can someone explain why conditional rendering fixes the async issue of setState in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, setstate

So i am making little blog post project and in this I call an api for states "mainblog" and "relatedBlogs". When i try to pass mainBlog to a component "Post", it gives me an error on reloading saying that my mainBlog is null (which is the initial state). But it works fine on a re-render (not a reload). I am guessing it is because the setState function is async and it updates mainBlog too late.

My question is: why does putting a conditional rendering fix this issue? I have put:

```
mainBlog && (
                     <div>
                         <Post post={mainBlog} />
                         <h2 className='py-4 text-3xl font-bold'>Related Blogs</h2>
                         <div className='flex flex-col gap-y-7'>
                             {relatedBlogs.map((blog) => (
                                 <Post key={blog.id} post={blog} />
                             ))}
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 )
```

and it somehow fixes this issue. Why is that? Why is it checking the condition AFTER the async setState function has finished.

Main code:

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AppContext } from '../context/AppContext';
import Post from '../components/Post';
import Spinner from '../components/Spinner';

export default function DetailBlog() {
    const { loading, setLoading } = useContext(AppContext);
    const [mainBlog, setMainBlog] = useState(null);
    const [relatedBlogs, setRelatedBlogs] = useState([]);
    const location = useLocation();
    const blogId = location.pathname.split('/').at(-1);
    const newBaseUrl = "https://codehelp-apis.vercel.app/api/get-blog";


    async function fetchBlogData() {
        setLoading(true);
        let url = `${newBaseUrl}?blogId=${blogId}`
        try {
            const result = await fetch(url);
            const data = await result.json();
            console.log("api res");
            console.log(data);
            setMainBlog(data.blog);
            setRelatedBlogs(data.relatedBlogs);
            console.log(mainBlog);
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (blogId) {
            fetchBlogData();
        }
    }, [location.pathname]);
    return (
        <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-x-1 relative">
            {mainBlog && <Header text={`${blogId} - ${mainBlog.title}`} />}
            <div className='max-w-[620px] w-11/12 py-3 flex flex-col gap-y-7 my-[70px]'>
                {loading ? (
                    <Spinner />
                ) : mainBlog && (
                    <div>
                        <Post post={mainBlog} />
                        <h2 className='py-4 text-3xl font-bold'>Related Blogs</h2>
                        <div className='flex flex-col gap-y-7'>
                            {relatedBlogs.map((blog) => (
                                <Post key={blog.id} post={blog} />
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
            <BackButton />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I was expecting a blank page assuming that the conditional rendering checks only the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

you add the condition "mainBlog &&", which means only when mainBlog has data(not null or undefined), then the code after "&&" will work. In your case, only after setState is called, then mainBlog has data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).